# Alternative to Copy Features in ModelBuilder to display a result

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, sql, select-by-attribute

I have created a model that takes in a raster, converts it to a point shapefile, then extracts a set of points based on location, then further selects a set of points based on a SQL expression. I tried to run it once but it was taking absolutely forever. I would have thought this step to be akin to 'Export Data' in the regular window. Is this the right method? Current model creation below.

The goal of this procedure is to find a region of high density crops in a selected country. I will eventually need to determine the coordinate footprint of the area so I can export that information to fine tune a forecast model to focus on that particular area.

[image: Model]

Comment: Your "Secondly" looks like a second question which is better researched/asked separately.

Comment: Whether this is the "right method" depends on what the objective is.  If you edit the question to explain what you need to achieve (rather than focusing on how you presently are failing to achieve it) you will increase the likelihood of getting useful, working, objective answers.

Comment: I think the SELECT tool mapBaker mentioned below looks to be my best option if I can get the SQL expression right, but I'll try to clarify a little better above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Select](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000005000000) tool

> Extracts features from an input feature class or input feature layer,
>   typically using a select or Structured Query Language (SQL) expression
>   and stores them in an output feature class.

Comment: Didn't we (I mean you) answer this in another post yesterday? Looking at the model the slow run time would be due to the overall number of features: raster to point generates lots of points! Are you sure that it's just the export that's taking a long time? Are you sure it's the tool and not slow disc or network access? Either way, @mapBaker is right, the select tool will do the work of select layer by attribute and copy features all in one - two for the price of one! That's a bargain.

Comment: There are a lot of points to run through, but the initial R2P is actually pretty fast. It was just the end copy features that was taking a really long time. I can kick out the second question, but it was rolled in with the first so I thought I'd put them together. I had looked at the Select tool, but didn't think it was going to do what I wanted, but I'll take another look. Thanks!

Comment: The Select tool worked once I added the Summary Statistics and Get Field Value tool. May be an easier way, but it works for me, so good enough. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I think we were talking about the "Select Data" tool... hah!